# Set parenting with automatic weight causes my mesh to deform in the abdominal and pelvic area

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am trying to set a mesh parenting with automatic weight to a skeleton I created. When I do so, I go from this:[image]

to this:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search I solved it. I had to CTRL+A in Pose Mode and Apply Pose as Rest Pose before I set the automatic weight.